# MySql query taking long time while querying 5s resolution 4 years data

Tags: mysql, csv

I am downloading MySql query. It is taking long time. Long solution I found is, download 2 months data at a time. I don't like to do it almost 25 times same thing. Is there a better way I can query and get more months data if not years data?
Information: My data starts on 2018-11-01 and there are many sensors data. I am querying sensor 20 data. It is sunlight value. At night its value will be less than 20 and I am dropping that data as well. I want to select values during daytime only. Hence, final_value>20

My code:

```
SELECT datetime,sensor_value,sensor_id
FROM sensor.timeseries 
WHERE ((datetime<'2019-01-01') and (datetime> '2018-11-01') and sensor_id in (20) and  sensor_value>20);
```

Present output:

```
SELECT datetime,sensor_value,sensor_id
FROM sensor.timeseries 
WHERE ((datetime<'2019-01-01') and (datetime> '2018-11-01') and sensor_id in (20) and  sensor_value>20) 150755 row(s) returned  0.250 sec / 43.625 sec
```

screenshot:
[image]

I want to query and store more rows? Also, how can I save this data automatically, not manually? At least this saves some time for me.

Update: based on the below received suggestions:

Query1: I will run the following first

```
ALTER TABLE sensor.timeseries ADD INDEX new_index (datetime,sensor_id,sensor_value)
```

Query2: I will then run the following

```
SELECT datetime,sensor_value,sensor_id FROM sensor.timeseries  WHERE ((datetime<'2019-01-01') and (datetime> '2018-11-01') and sensor_id in (20) and  sensor_value>20);
```

Am I correct?

Comment: Do you have an index on field measdatetime?

Comment: @JonathanHernández can you specify what mean by index? I just shared a screenshot. Thanks

Comment: Here are some useful references for MySQL indexes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html, https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_create_index.asp, https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/, http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones  can you specify what is index in my case?

Comment: @Mainland start with `EXPLAIN SELECT` to be able to see what caused such execution delay

Comment: @user973254 I really appreciate for this wonderful solution. I just ran this and got the following result.       ` id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
 1 SIMPLE timeseries  ref datetime_ID,modbus_id modbus_id 4 const 15501625 33.31 Using where` The question is, what does it mean? I understand it is trying to check 15 million rows. Am I correct?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Query1: I will run the following first `ALTER TABLE sensor.timeseries ADD INDEX new_index (datetime,sensor_id,sensor_value)`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Query2: I will then run the following `SELECT datetime,sensor_value,sensor_id
FROM sensor.timeseries 
WHERE ((datetime<'2019-01-01') and (datetime> '2018-11-01') and sensor_id in (20) and  sensor_value>20);` Am I correct?

Comment: @JonathanHernández I have updated my question about creating  `index`. Can you confirm will this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can change to modbus_readout_id = 20 and try that way.
There is another answer about saving output to a file
[How to save MySQL query output to excel or .txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file)

Comment: That did not help as well.

Answer (score 1):

To improve your query performance add a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX da_sid_sva
ON timeseries (datetime, sensor_id , sensor_value);
```

There is no need for `sensor_id in (20)` , you could simply write `sensor_id =20`... this will make no performance improvement.

Comment: Query1: I will run the following first `ALTER TABLE sensor.timeseries ADD INDEX new_index (datetime,sensor_id,sensor_value)`

Comment: Query2: I will then run the following `SELECT datetime,sensor_value,sensor_id
FROM sensor.timeseries 
WHERE ((datetime<'2019-01-01') and (datetime> '2018-11-01') and sensor_id in (20) and  sensor_value>20);` Am I correct?

Comment: My queries failed. I tried four combinations of index. All 3 together and separately. All failed with common error `15:47:36 ALTER TABLE sensor.timeseries ADD INDEX new_index(sensor_value) Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 30.015 sec`

Answer (score 1):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE timeseries`

Can there ever be two readings for a sensor at exactly the same time?  If so, can you avoid such?

Tentatively, you need *this* schema:

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries (
    sensor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    sensor_value FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, datetime)
);
```

> 150755 row(s) returned

That will take time -- for both performing the query and for shoveling it over the network.

No extra indexes will be beneficial for the query you mentioned.  If you do have other queries, or you frequently request data from multiple sensors at the same time, let's see them.

(Minor bug:  If a reading can happen exactly at midnight, note that the query as it is written eliminates the first midnight.)

> I want to query and store more rows?

`INSERT` lets you store more rows.

> Also, how can I save this data automatically, not manually?

Where does the data come from?

> 15 million rows

No problem.  If you store a billion rows, there are some more things to look at.

> ALTER TABLE sensor.timeseries ADD INDEX new_index (datetime, ...

It is almost never useful to have a composite index *starting* with a `DATETIME` column.